# Getting the name of a coffeescript class?

Tags: coffeescript, introspection

Will the following alert "Foo" in all browsers, even when minified?

```
class Foo

alert(Foo.name)
```

Nothing is stated in the doc, I know that IE has problems with function names, and I'm confused with the many issues opened about this, like [any](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/729) [of](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/714) [these](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2196) [issues](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2052) [!](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/494)

Comment: WRT minified code - it really depends on the minifier and the configuration you pass to it. Most can be configured not to touch named function statements (like UglifyJS's `--no-mangle-functions`), so the `name` property should work fine there (unless the browser doesn't support it at all). Of course, with the property CoffeeScript defines manually since 1.3.3, it should always work regardless of minification (as its added as a plain string literal property)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That may depend on which version of the CoffeeScript compiler you're using. In the lastest stable release (1.3.3), a "name" property isn't generated by default.

```
class Foo
```

compiles into

```
var Foo;
Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}
  return Foo;
})();
```

Since the `name` property is non-standard and currently not supported by the IE, you cannot really rely on it cross-browser. Detailed information about this are available at the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name

Comment: Are you hinting that a later or older version would generate a name property? Also is there some flag that will override this default or do you have to add the property yourself.

Comment: I think it has actually been removed, so in older versions you might still find this behavior, yes.

Answer (score 10):

From within any method of class `Foo` that is included in `Foo.prototype`, you can insert the line

```
console.log @constructor.name
```

and it will write

```
Foo
```

to your console log. HTH.

Comment: It is now clear (see end of https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2052 ) that it is not supported. Go and ask for it if you want it too!

Comment: Can't you just use Foo.constructor.name ? @Marc-AndréLafortune